# Utilizing file.readline() with a mix of integers and strings

Tags: python, file, readline

I'm rather new to Python, and I'm working on a game, saving multiple stats. However, while trying to load these stats using `readline()`, I happen to get jumbled values, mixing the various stats saved.

```
# Save
...
file.write(str(p_lv)) # 1 (line 3)
file.write(str(p_xp)) # 10 (line 4)
file.write(str(p_swd)) # s01 (line 5)
...
# Load
...
p_lv = int(file.readline(3))
p_xp = int(file.readline(4))
p_swd = file.readline(5)
...
```

When I make a save ingame, it saves the entire save as a single string, like so:

```
8010015s01100Nutik
```

I attempt to call the load command with that save in the box, however, it turns out to be:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '5s01'
```

it mixes up where I'm at, is there a way I can get it so it reads, for example, the fourth item I wrote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are not writing the newline.

Change each write call with:

```
file.write(str(...) + '\n')
```

Also, `file.readline()` does not take an argument. Remove the number argument to it, or if you are not using all the lines, do:

```
lines = file.readlines()

x = int(lines[3])
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to save each stat value on a separate line in the file, then you will have to manually add the newline character upon save. Some like:

```
file.write(str(p_lv) + "\n") # 1 (line 3)
file.write(str(p_xp) + "\n") # 10 (line 4)
file.write(str(p_swd) + "\n") # s01 (line 5)
```

When you read the file back, use the `readlines` method, which actually returns an array of lines from the read file; hence you will be able to access the data in order:

```
lines = file.readlines()
p_lv = int(lines[3])
p_xp = int(lines[4])
p_swd = lines[5]
```

Even better solution would be to serialize/deserialize stats in JSON format: keep your stats in a dictionary, for example:

```
stats = {
   'p_lv': 123,
   'p_xp': 234,
   'p_swd': 'some string'
}
```

and you would save as:

```
import json
with open('filename.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(stats))
```

and read it back as:

```
with open('filename.txt') as f:
    stats = json.loads(f.read())
```